# How to align multiple divs containing SearchBars and Sliders in React?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, tsx

I have a React component MultiSearchBar where I've implemented a layout with multiple SearchBar components and a commented-out section with SliderComponent components. The current layout aligns the SearchBar components horizontally, and now I want to add another div with both SearchBar and SliderComponent components. However, I'm struggling to align them properly.

Here is the code of my container that contains the Search bars and Sliders:

```
import React from 'react';
import { SearchBar } from './searchBar';
import SliderComponent from './Slider'; // Import the SliderComponent


export const MultiSearchBar: React.FC = () => {
  // Define a function to handle search for each individual search bar
  const handleSearch = (query: string, searchIndex: number) => {
    console.log(`Search Bar ${searchIndex + 1}: ${query}`);
    // You can perform any additional logic or state management here
  };

  return (
    <div style={{
          minHeight: '100vh',
          justifyContent: 'space-between',
      }}>
      {/* <SliderComponent defaultValue={50} /> */}
      <div style={{
        textAlign: 'center', // Center text
        marginBottom: '40px',
        fontSize: '20px',
        fontWeight: 'bold',
      }}>
        Моля, задайте критериите си тук.
      </div>
      <div style={{
        display: 'flex',
        gap: '50px',
        flexDirection: 'row',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center', // Center horizontally
        height: '38px',
        // margin: '0 auto', // Center the entire block
      }}>
        <SearchBar onSearch={(query) => handleSearch(query, 0)} />
        <SearchBar onSearch={(query) => handleSearch(query, 1)} />
        <SearchBar onSearch={(query) => handleSearch(query, 2)} />
        <SearchBar onSearch={(query) => handleSearch(query, 3)} />
      </div>

      <div style={{
            display: 'flex',
            gap: '50px',
            flexDirection: 'row',
            alignItems: 'center',
            justifyContent: 'center', // Center horizontally
            height: '38px',
            // margin: '0 auto', // Center the entire block
        }}>
        <SliderComponent defaultValue={50} />
        <SliderComponent defaultValue={50} />
        <SliderComponent defaultValue={50} />
        <SearchBar onSearch={(query) => handleSearch(query, 3)} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
  };

  export default MultiSearchBar;
```

I am wondering how to structure it and what is the best practice. Any guidance or code examples would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

[image: This is how it is now]
[image: This is how it should look]

Comment: have a look at the built-in `Grid` component from MUI https://mui.com/material-ui/react-grid/